# Opencv - finding vessel contour after canny edge detection

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an image of a vessel. After canny edge detection and different processing I managed to get this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaYtp.png). The vessel is clearly seen but I would like to get the contour of this vessel. How should I do it?

Comment: How is that not the contour? What is missing? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Those are just two lines. Cv.findcontours would find contours of that two lines separately. I want one contour of vessel containing borders of the image which are inside the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get two seperate contours is that you apply Canny edge detector to your grayscale image. This gives the result of "white lines" - edges on a blank image. The `cv2.findContours()` in laymans term looks for connected white pixels on a binary image. So because you have two seperate lines it finds two contours. The `cv2.findContours()` returns an array of points of the contours so before you search for your region of interest you must first connect those two lines to obtain only one contour. You can do this by itterating through the points and append the points that have values 0 for `x` or `y` and/or have the value of the images height or width. This will give you 4 points - start and end point of the first contour plus start and end of the second. Then you can measure the distance between those points to determine which fit togheter. Formula for distance between two points is as I recall is `sqrt((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2)`. So if you calculate the distance of one point to the remaining 3, the shortest distance means that those two points fit togheter (as do the two points fit togheter that are further away). So now you have the start and end point of both lines and you can connect them. Ofcorse you can make other criterion like if the first point has `x==0` and `y>0` then make a line to the point `(0,0)` and from there another line to the second point, so that you don't cut out part of the region of interest. I have made a simple example to show you the logic of achieving this. Note that this is not a working solution for automatization - to achieve that you will have to upgrade it a lot.

Example code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('vessel.png')
h, w, ch = img.shape
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(img,100,200)
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
points = []

cv2.imshow('edges', edges)

for cnt in contours:
    for i in cnt[:,0]:
        x = int(i[0])
        y = int(i[1])
        if x == 0:
            points.append((x,y))
        elif y == 0:
            points.append((x,y))
        elif w-1<= x <= w+1:
            points.append((x,y))
        elif h-1<= y <= h+1:
            points.append((x,y))

if len(points) == 4:
    x1, y1 = points[0]
    x2, y2 = points[1]
    x3, y3 = points[2]
    x4, y4 = points[3]

dist1 = np.sqrt((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)
dist2 = np.sqrt((x3-x1)**2 + (y3-y1)**2)    
dist3 = np.sqrt((x4-x1)**2 + (y4-y1)**2)

if dist2 < dist1 and dist2 < dist3:
    cv2.line(edges, (x3,y3), (x1,y1), 255, 1)
    cv2.line(edges, (x2,y2), (x4,y4), 255, 1)

_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, 0, (0,255,0), 2)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imshow('edges+lines', edges)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Original image:

[image]

Edges:

[image]

Edges + lines:

[image]

Contours:

[image]

That being said, you could try to threshold your image instead of searching for edges. That could give you one contour from the getgo and will make things a lot easier. Can't say for sure because you haven't posted the original image!

Example code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('vessel.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, 0, (0,255,0), 2)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thresholded image:

[image]

Contours:

[image]